# Can findViewById(android.R.id.content) ever return null for Snackbars?

Tags: android, findviewbyid, snackbar

I want to be able to display Snackbars but I am confused by this notion that I have to supply it with a View. You'd think it'd allow you to display the Snackbar at the bottom of the screen by default, but maybe I am missing something.

Anyway supposedly this can be done by using the view:

`findViewById(android.R.id.content)`

However I get a warning that this may be null even though it always seems to work wherever I try it. When can it possibly be null?

Comment: Are you in an AppCompatActivity?

Comment: I'm usually either in an AppCompatActivity or a Fragment

Comment: For appCompatActivity it can be related to this issue : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203345

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findViewById` can always be null, if you try to find a view that doesn't exist in the current layout.

The warning is just a help. 
It's probably very generic and if you look inside the source of the [Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) class, you will find this method:

```
@Nullable
public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return getWindow().findViewById(id);
}
```

The `Nullable` annotation just informs the compiler that there might be a possibility of getting a `null` reference here and Lint will react to this. It doesn't know how to differentiate between a `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` or some other call with `findViewById(R.id.myCustomLayoutId)`. You could probably add the Lint check yourself however.

You can safely use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` whenever you're inside an `Activity`.

You can safely use `getView()` inside a `Fragment` whenever `onCreateView` has been called.

Comment: What about when you're inside a Fragment but you want the Snackbar to display on the bottom of the whole screen? getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content) or something?

Comment: Ah yes, you can call `getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` to get the root view.

Comment: It's also telling me getView() might be null -- same idea? Might be null but probably not?

Comment: `getView()` is also annotated with `@Nullable`, so it can also return null. It will return null if you call it before `onViewCreated` has been called.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the activity if your not in AppCompatActivity

```
public static void snackBar(Activity activity, String MESSAGE) {
    Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), MESSAGE, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If you have a context you can try like this

```
public static void snackBar(Context context, String MESSAGE) {
    Snackbar.make(((Activity)context).findViewById(android.R.id.content), MESSAGE, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```